# Sending file and String value making error in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have to upload image and also send `String` data in post method using `Retrofit 2`. I'm using the flowing method to do that.

```
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("signup/step3")
Call<BasicModel> completeRegistration(
    /*All Basic Parameter*/
    @Field("mobile_no") String mobileNo,

    /*For User Image*/
    @Part MultipartBody.Part photoFile

);
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only one encoding annotation is allowed.
         for method AllNetworkCalls.completeRegistration
         at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:695)
         at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:686)
         at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseMethodAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:266)
         at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:169)
         at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
         at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
         at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
         at $Proxy1.completeRegistration(Unknown Source)
         at com.sslwireless.app.Activities.SignUp.RegistrationActivity_5.completeRegistration(RegistrationActivity_5.java:244)
         at com.sslwireless.app.Activities.SignUp.RegistrationActivity_5.access$1100(RegistrationActivity_5.java:51)
         at com.sslwireless.app.Activities.SignUp.RegistrationActivity_5$5.onClick(RegistrationActivity_5.java:132)
         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Is there any other way I can do that ?

Comment: I dont think that you can use `@FormUrlEncoded` and `@Multipart` together for the same request. Try to remove FromUrlEncoded it should work

Comment: is i remove `@FromUrlEncoded` then i get error for `@Field` .

Comment: i think you need to use `@Body` instead of `@Field` regarding it is a Post request

Comment: I also use `@Body` , the problem is multipart can't for encode. That's the main problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Retrofit 2, you need to use either OkHttp’s RequestBody or MultipartBody.Part classes and encapsulate your file into a request body. Let’s have a look at the interface definition for file uploads.

```
public interface FileUploadService {  
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part("description") RequestBody description,
                              @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
}
```

**in Java file**

```
private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {  
    // create upload service client
    FileUploadService service =
            ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);

    // https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
    // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
    File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);

    // add another part within the multipart request
    String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
    RequestBody description =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);

    // finally, execute the request
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(description, body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                               Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.v("Upload", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the parameter for `RequestBody` ?